# .NET KeyUp handler: is it not necessary to cast the sender to the correct type?

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, casting, handler

I'm currently refactoring a VB.NET application of mine and I bumped into something I didn't expect. There are 2 KeyUp event handlers, for which the code is mostly identical, that I wish to reduce to 1 event handler. One of the handlers is used by a WPF ListBox, the other by a WPF DataGrid. These are the handlers:

```
Protected Sub ListBox_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)

    Dim box As ListBox = CType(sender, ListBox)

    If e.Key = Key.J AndAlso Keyboard.Modifiers = ModifierKeys.Control Then
        If box.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
            Actions.TryViewInExplorer(CType(box.SelectedItem, TrackInfoViewModel).TrackInfo.Path)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub DataGrid_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)

    Dim box As DataGrid = CType(sender, DataGrid)

    If e.Key = Key.J AndAlso Keyboard.Modifiers = ModifierKeys.Control Then
        If box.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
            Actions.TryViewInExplorer(CType(box.SelectedItem, TrackInfoViewModel).TrackInfo.Path)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

As you can see, I cast the sender object to the correct item container, before trying to call the function "SelectedItem".
When refactoring these 2 handlers to 1, I noticed that Visual Studio doesn't throw any errors when calling "SelectedItem" directly on the sender without first casting it:

```
Protected Sub ListBox_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)

    If e.Key = Key.J AndAlso Keyboard.Modifiers = ModifierKeys.Control Then
        If box.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
            Actions.TryViewInExplorer(CType(sender.SelectedItem, TrackInfoViewModel).TrackInfo.Path)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I wasn't expecting this to be possible. Is this supposed to be possible? And would it be good practice to keep such solution?

Comment: Check for `Option Strict On`... my guess is that it's *not* on, otherwise `sender.SelectedItem` wouldn't compile.

Comment: You are right. It was disabled. Enabling tells me late binding is not allowed. That answers my  question. Thanks!